# Listview item under edittext

Tags: android, listview, layout

The last item of Listview is always under editText. How to fix it appearing above editText? my xml is below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
      <ListView android:id="@+id/android:list" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
      android:layout_above="@+id/txtTo_e"/>            
    <EditText android:id="@+id/txtTo_e"
         android:layout_width="230dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:textSize="18sp"
         android:hint="Compose"
         android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"/>
   <Button android:text="Done"
         android:id="@+id/btnD_e"
         android:layout_width="85dip"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"            
         android:layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
         android:layout_alignParentRight="true"/>                                               
</RelativeLayout>
```

Thank you.

PS: When I opened this forum, setting toolbar was invisible. Sorry. In my PC, I couldn't click comment button and see toolbar. sorry for any inconvenient to u.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Provide more information and more code as to the specifics of your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe changing

`android:layout_below="@+id/txtToText_e"`

to

`android:layout_above="@+id/txtToText_e"`

and removing `android:layout_above="@+id/txtTM"` helps?

Where is your `"@+id/txtTM"` view btw?

Answer (score 0):

You are using Relativelayout, you need to put the code of the button above the editText.